# How can I enable debug mode in Sitecore CDP and Sitecore Personalize?

Tags: personalization, cdp, sitecore-personalize

In Sitecore CDP and Sitecore Personalize, debug mode can be turned on to see all the configuration and data in the platform. How can this mode be turned on in the platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debug mode enables visibility of all the data and configuration stored in Sitecore CDP and Sitecore Personalize.

Go to the name of your tenant, then your name, then Feature Flags. There is a feature flag for debug mode that can be switched on to see the underlying data structure in the CDP.

After enabling debug mode, you will see an orange cog on most pages in the platform. You can click this orange cog to see all the data in the CDP being represented on that page.

[image]